# Creating model managers

Tags: django, django-models

My models.py of blog application is  like this -

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,    
                     self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices= STATUS_CHOICES,     
              default='draft')

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager() 


    class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

When i run  `Post.published.filter(title__startswith='Who')` in shell

It gives me shell full of errors like this -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management       
/commands/shell.py", line 77, in handle_noargs
self.run_shell(shell=interface)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management    
/commands/shell.py", line 65, in run_shell
raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'published'
```

Confused with it. Help me if there is another way too.
Giving bith ImportError as well as AttributeError
Do i need to import something more in shell.
Already imported

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from blog.models import Post
```

in my shell

Comment: Are you sure your shell wasn't started before you added the manager? I.e. does the problem persist when you re-open your shell?

Comment: Also, note the indent for `class Meta` and `def __str__`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to restart shell.

Comment: NP, I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks good, so likely your shell wasn't started before you added the manager. 
Restart your shell and try again.